# how to provide relative address to read a file in java

Tags: java, eclipse, path

what I want to ask seems so simple and crazy but since I am so beginner I dare to ask you guys.
I want to give relative address to read a file in eclipse java.  my java file is in common package and json file is in resources package in the same project. but I do not know how to provide relative address to that.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/?/file.json"));
```

so I have a project:

```
> src/main/java
   >com.project.cc.restful.common
   >com.project.cc.restful.resources
```

any help?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a path that is **relative** to your **working directory**. The working directory is a configurable parameter. In eclipse the default is usually the root folder of the project (not the source code folder!). It can be configured in the "Run Configurations.." menu.

To be sure, run your application once with `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))` to see the absolute path to your working directory. Once you have that, use `../../Resources` (or something similar) to get to the resources directory using a relative path.

Comment: I am looking for (something similar) dude! I do not know how to provide the address

Comment: use "../" to go up one level (to the parent directory). So if you need to go up one level, then go into a directory called "blah", use "../blah". If you need to go up two levels, then go into "blah", use "../../blah"

Comment: @user3409650 Wait. Are your resources in the same folder as the java sources? First of all, that's not very good. Second, if that is the case, then your path is probably "src/com/project/cc/restful/resources"

Comment: ya they are on the same folder and I tried both src/com/project/cc/restful/resources and src/main/java/com/project/cc/restful/resources but still not correct :(((

Comment: what's your working directory? And what is the (absolute) path to the resources?

Comment: The absolute path is: /restful/src/main/java/com/project/cc/restful/resources/file.json

Comment: its /home/user/projectFolder/mainProject/restful

Comment: then the path is src/main/java/com/project/cc/restful/resources/file.json

Comment: thanks dude for your help but again it is not correct :(( when I put the file here: /home/user/file.json it works but when I want to read from that path it does not. what might cause this?